# Get resolution from multiple widgets

Tags: c++, qt

How do I get the resolution from multiple widgets inside a layout.

For example I have the following:

```
ui.horizontalLayout_2->addWidget(&test1);
ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(&test2); 
ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(&test3);
ui.horizontalLayout->addWidget(&test4);
```

Each of which is in a seperate window inside the layout.

I created this function not really understanding how to approach this problem which gives me the total resolution of the entire window.

```
void Widget::getScreenGeomerty()
{
    QScreen* screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
    QRect  screenGeometry = screen->geometry();
    int height = screenGeometry.height();
    int width = screenGeometry.width();

    qDebug() << "Screen height: " << height;
    qDebug() << "Screen width: " << width;
}
```

What is the correct way to go about doing this.

```
#include "GLWidget.h"

class TestRecorder : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestRecorder( QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~TestRecorder();


private:
    Ui::TFMRecorderClass ui;
    GLWidget test1;
    GLWidget test2;
    GLWidget test3;
    GLWidget test4;
};
```

Comment: Which resolution are you looking for: resolution of the whole window, or of each widget? I wasn't sure based on your question which you wanted. Both have member functions to get h/w

Comment: @alteredinstance resolution of each widget. Not sure how to do this. I think my current functions gets the resolution of the entire screen.

Comment: Gotcha, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `QWidget`-derived objects have `height` and `width` properties - Your `test1, ... , test4` objects all are `QWidget`-derived.

Simply reference their members, just like you did with `screenGeometry` (also a `QWidget`) e.g.

```
test1->height(); //Y Resolution
test1->width();  //x Resolution
```

Here you can find the documentation on [height](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#height-prop) and [width](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#width-prop)

EDIT: 
To solve the issue of being unable to access `height()` & `width()`, forward declare the `QGLWidget` class in your .h file. Such as:

```
#include "GLWidget.h"

class QGLWidget;

class TestRecorder : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

// etc...
```

Comment: It won't let me access those functions. So you're saying after I add them to the layout I can just get the height and width?

Comment: Typo: `test1->height` --> `test1->height()` etc.

Comment: Can I see the code for when you set up `test1` and such? There are a couple hoops you have to jump through. You may need to forward declare QWidget in the top of your header file, such as adding the line `Class QWidget;`. Otherwise your compiler may not know any of the members of `test1` in the .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks @G.M. , fixed

Comment: It only allows me to access heightMM(), etc and not height(). @alteredinstance. I did declare my test1 in the header file.

Comment: @testStackFlow Sorry, re-read the comment, I got confused and edited it.

Comment: @alteredinstance I added the class above

Comment: @testStackFlow Check my answer, might be more clear

Comment: @alteredinstance I still couldn't access it because it thinks that I want to use  the Qpaint height() function so instead I did `test1.geometry().height()`. I think that should be more appropriate?

Comment: @testStackFlow Hmm.. `geometry()` is still a `QWidget` member so I'm not sure why it would let you use that and not `height()`... Where is your `Widget` class defined? It may need the forward declaration inside of that and not `TestRecorder`.